# Android - Populate an ListView

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, android-listview

CreateDatabse:

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
//If database not exists copy it from the assets

boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
if(!mDataBaseExist)
{
    this.getReadableDatabase();
    this.close();
    try 
    {
        //Copy the database from assests
        copyDataBase();

    } 
    catch (IOException mIOException) 
    {
        throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
    }
}
}
```

TestAdapter:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;



import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TestAdapter extends Activity 
{

ArrayList<Horario> array = new ArrayList<Horario>();
protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter";

private final Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

public TestAdapter(Context context) 
{
    this.mContext = context;
    mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
}

public TestAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException 
{
    try 
    {
        mDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } 
    catch (IOException mIOException) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
        throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
    }
    return this;
}

public TestAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    try 
    {
        mDbHelper.openDataBase();
        mDbHelper.close();
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    } 
    catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
        throw mSQLException;
    }
    return this;
}

public void close() 
{
    mDbHelper.close();
}

 public Cursor getTestData()
 {
     try
     {
         String sql ="SELECT * FROM horarios";

         Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
         if (mCur!=null)
         {
            mCur.moveToNext();
         }
         return mCur;
     }
     catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
     {
         Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
         throw mSQLException;
     }

 }
 public ArrayList<Horario> getorigem(){

    String query = "select origem, destino From horarios";
    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, new String[]{});

    ArrayList<Horario> array = new ArrayList<Horario>();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String _origem = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("origem"));
        String _destino = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("destino"));
        array.add(new Horario(_origem, _destino));
    }
    return array;     

}

public void populateListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter();       
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Horario>{
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(TestAdapter.this, R.layout.item_view, array);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Make sure we have view to work with
        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView == null){
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
        }

        //Find the car to work with.
        Horario currentHorario = array.get(position);

        //Fill the view

        // Origem:
        TextView makeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_origem);
        makeText.setText(currentHorario.getOrigem());

        // Destino:
        TextView ConditionText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_destino);
        ConditionText.setText(currentHorario.getDestino());

        return itemView;

    }
}
}
```

and i try populate an ListView like this:

```
 public void populateListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayAdapter<Horario> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Horario>{
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(TestAdapter.this, R.layout.item_view, array);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView == null){
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
        }


        Horario currentHorario = array.get(position);

        //Fill the view

        // Origem:
        TextView makeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_origem);
        makeText.setText(currentTime.getOrigem());

        // Destino:
        TextView makeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_destino);
        makeText.setText(currentTime.getDestino());

        return itemView;

    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(getBaseContext());
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

    }

    public void search(View v) {

        setContentView(R.layout.list_view);

        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(getBaseContext());
        mDbHelper.open();

        mDbHelper.getorigem();
        mDbHelper.populateListView();
        mDbHelper.close();

    }
}
```

but it get error and close when i click the button
LogCat

```
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): Process: arr.app, PID: 1168
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     ... 11 more
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4532)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at arr.app.TestAdapter$MyListAdapter.<init>(TestAdapter.java:119)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at arr.app.TestAdapter.populateListView(TestAdapter.java:111)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at arr.app.MainActivity.search(MainActivity.java:32)
02-24 08:29:32.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     ... 14 more
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnsearch"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="search"
    android:text="Search" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbldestino"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblorigem"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblorigem"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:text="Destino"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblorigem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="Origem"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtorigem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblorigem"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblorigem"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtdestino"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lbldestino"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lbldestino"
    android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i start programing to android about 1 week and im at some days trying slove that problem
appreciate any help

Comment: post TestAdapter class code

Comment: from your logcat may be your databse object **mDb** is null

Comment: The stacktrace is about initializing a `Toast` but there's no toast in your code. Please update the stacktrace or code, whichever is out of date.

Comment: Can you post your mDbHelper.createDataBase() method?

Comment: logcat updated and mDbHelper.createDataBse() published

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your adapter is extending `Activity` and not implementing `setContentView` inside the `onCreate` method, so it fails when calling `findViewById(R.id.list_view);`. You need to use content of your `populateListView` method inside the `MainActivity`, assuming that the `list_view` layout file (R.layout.list_view) contains a `ListView` called `list_view` (R.id.list_view).

```
public void search(View v) {

    setContentView(R.layout.list_view);

    TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(getBaseContext());
    mDbHelper.open();

    ArrayAdapter<Horario> adapter = new MyListAdapter(mDbHelper.getorigem());
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDbHelper.close();

}
```

In your `MyListAdapter` modify your constructor to:

```
public MyListAdapter(ArrayList<Horario> arrayHorario) {
    array = arrayHorario;
    super(TestAdapter.this, R.layout.item_view, array);
}
```

To call the search on click button, use the following method:

```
bt_search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        search(v);
    }
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: ok, i moved populateListView and MyListAdapter to MainActivity and now dont get error.
but list view dont show any values

Comment: call the search method from the MainActivity onCreate

Comment: but i wanna use search method when i click on button Search - (from activity_main.xml) ...android:onClick="search"

Comment: oh i see... you mean it does not show the list when you click the button? Did you implemented the onClickListener method?

Comment: i have created that - bt_search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  public void onClick(View v) {    - and inside that i copy - public void search(View v) {   - but it still the same

Comment: I updated my answer with the correct implementation of your onClick

Comment: I have updated my answer, try it now. By the way, you should put your MyListAdapter in a separated class, and don't use an activity to get the values from the database... you can put those methods on the class that you use to create the database, or another class that extends this one, but don't use the activity.

Comment: i have moved MyListAdapter to TestAdapter, but - ArrayAdapter<Horario> adapter = new TestAdapter.MyListAdapter(); - get error

Comment: You should start a new question posting your new code and new error log and avoid comments, this question is already answered.